# Access parent Entity in Complex Type with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table that has quite a few columns. From a DB perspective this is not a problem for me (I need all that information at the same time anyway), but my Entity gets a bit too big, so I would like to group some functionality in a *Complex Type*. Problem is that I also need to add some logic, and therefore I need to access the parent Entity to access other properties.

Is it somehow possible to pass the parent Entity, i.e. through the constructor?
I am using Database First.
What is the best way to handle this?

Example:

```
Animal (Entity)
- Id
- AmountOfLegs
- Weight
- Height
- Looks (ComplexType)
    - BaseColor
    - HasTexture
    - GetTextureUrl () => { return BaseUrl + Parent.Id + ".jpg"; } // Error: Parent not accessible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Entity Framework Table Splitting feature to design this properly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715645.aspx

You'll end up having different entities for different parts of your table. Those will have navigation properties pointing at each other.

Comment: Sorry, took a while before had time testing this one! Works like a charm, thanks!